# Пагинация для категории произвольных типов записей wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Создал свой тип записи. Теперь создаю свой шаблон в котором их вывожу и все бы без проблем, но никак не могу сделать пагинацию к ним. Наведите на мысль. Вот код:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Шаблон базарчик
*/
get_header(); // подключаем header.php ?> 
<section>
<div class="container">

<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
<div class="left-content">


    <?php 
        $count = 0;
        $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'post_type' => 'bazar'
        );
        $bazar = new WP_Query( $args );
        if($bazar->have_posts()) :
        while($bazar->have_posts()) :
                $bazar->the_post(); 
    ?>
                <div class="product-1 box<?php if( $count%2 == 0 ) { echo '-2'; }; $count++; ?>">
                    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">  
                        <?php
                            $cvet = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cvet', true);
                            $razmer = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'razmer', true);
                            $nomer = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'nomer', true);
                            $gorod = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gorod', true);
                            $name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name', true);
                            $telephone = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'telephone', true);
                         ?>
                        <ul class="products products-cat">  
                            <?php 
                                echo "<li><b>Цвет:</b> $cvet</li>";
                                echo "<li><b>Размер:</b> $razmer</li>";
                                echo "<li><b>Номер:</b> $nomer</li>";
                                echo "<li><b>Город:</b> $gorod</li>";
                                echo "<li><b>Имя:</b> $name</li>";
                                echo "<li><b>Телефон:</b> $telephone</li>";
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="cat-date">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
                                Дата публикации: <?php echo get_the_date('Y-m-d'); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- .post -->
                </div><!-- .boxes -->
            <?php endwhile;
                if ( function_exists('kama_pagenavi') ){
                        kama_pagenavi();
                } elseif ( get_next_posts_link() || get_previous_posts_link() )
                {
            ?>
                <div class="wp-navigation clearfix">
                    <div class="alignleft"><?php //next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries'); ?></div>
                    <div class="alignright"><?php //previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;'); ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>    
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- .left-content -->
<div class="right-content">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'Auth' ); ?>

        <div class="buy-btn">
            <a href="#">Продать</a>
        </div>
</div><!-- .right-content -->
<?php } else { ?>
<h2 class="auth-noreg-h2">Пожалуйста, авторизируйтесь чтобы просмотреть этот раздел.</h2>
<div class="auth-noreg">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'Auth' ); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div><!-- .container -->
</section>
<?php get_sidebar(); // подключаем sidebar.php ?>
<?php get_footer(); // подключаем footer.php ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решили? Я нашел способ, была аналогичная ситуация. В общем, везде нам рекомендуют следующий шаблон аргументов:

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_type' => 'bazar'
    );
```

У меня так не работало. Выдавало "Страница не найдена". На помощь пришла функция `get_query_var()` :

```
$args = array(
          'post_type' => 'movies', 
          'posts_per_page' => 2,
          'paged' => get_query_var( 'page', 1 )     

        );
```

Если вдруг так просто не прокатит, тогда нужно создать страницу Page и в настройках чтения выставить тип ссылок "имя поста".
Еще вот [ссылка на функцию пагинации](http://wp-kama.ru/id_8/alternativa-wp-pagenavi-bez-lishnix-zaprosov-k-bd-ili-keshu.html)

Answer (score 1):

Тоже столкнулся с данной проблемой и решение оказалось гораздо проще. При создании произвольного типа записи нужно разрешить пагинацию. По ключю 'rewrite' у меня значение 'pages' стояло в false и при переходе на site.ru/courses/page/2 выдавало 404 страницу. Исправил на true, обновил настройку постоянных ссылок в админке и все заработало.

```
$courses = array(
  /***/
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'rewrite' => array(
    'slug'       => 'courses/%coursescat%',
    'with_front' => false,
    'pages'      => true,
    'feeds'      => false,
    'feed'       => false
  ),
  'has_archive' => 'courses',
  /****/
);

register_post_type( 'courses', $courses );
```